# Consuming messages from Redis Stream using Consumer Groups in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, npm, redis, node-redis, redis-streams

Redis Consumer Groups is relatively a new feature in Redis and so I couldn't find a matured enough npm package that provide out of the box mechanism to read messages using consumer group. In Spring Data Redis, `onMessage(V message)` of `StreamListener` interface will be callback on every new message.

I am using [redis npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)  for Redis and I have to manage message reads by manually firing **XREADGROUP** command in an infinite loop. [Reference](https://github.com/tgrall/redis-streams-101-node/blob/master/consumer.js).
Though Spring redis library is continuously polling server for new messages and calling onMessage method on new messages but it's taken care by library itself not by the programmer.

From [Spring Data Redis](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.streams)

> While Pub/Sub relies on the broadcasting of transient messages (i.e. if you don’t listen, you miss a message), Redis Stream use a persistent, append-only data type that retains messages until the stream is trimmed. Another difference in consumption is that Pub/Sub registers a server-side subscription. Redis pushes arriving messages to the client while Redis Streams require active polling.

**Code Snippet From Spring Data Redis**

```
private void doLoop(K key) {

    do {

        try {

            // allow interruption
            Thread.sleep(0);

            List<V> read = readFunction.apply(key, pollState.getCurrentReadOffset());

            for (V message : read) {

                listener.onMessage(message);
                pollState.updateReadOffset(message.getId().getValue());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            cancel();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

            if (cancelSubscriptionOnError.test(e)) {
                cancel();
            }

            errorHandler.handleError(e);
        }
    } while (pollState.isSubscriptionActive());
}
```

I was wondering if there is any popular npm package through which I can find a better way to read messages from stream using consumer groups. I am looking something like this [redis-streams-broker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-streams-broker) This package seems unreliable to me as this has fewer downloads, not managed and no License